# Columnwise Summarize multiple sentences present in a list using the gensim summarizer

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am having a data-set consisting of faculty id and the feedback of students regarding the respective faculty. There are multiple comments for each faculty and therefore the comments regarding each faculty are present in the form of a list. I want to apply gensim summarization on the "comments" column of the data-set to generate the summary of faculty performance according to the student feedback.

Just for a trial I tried to summarize the feedbacks corresponding to the first faculty id. There are 8 distinct comments (sentences) in that particular feedback, still gensim throws an error ValueError: input must have more than one sentence.

```
df_test.head()
    csf_id  comments
0   9   [' good subject knowledge.', ' he has good kn...
1   10  [' good knowledge of subject. ', ' good subjec...
2   11  [' good at clearing the concepts interactive w...
3   12  [' clears concepts very nicely interactive wit...
4   13  [' good teaching ability.', ' subject knowledg...
from gensim.summarization import summarize
text = df_test["comments"][0]
print("Text")
print(text)
print("Summary")
print(summarize(text))
```

> ValueError: input must have more than one sentence

what changes shold i make so that the summarizer reads all the sentenses and summarizes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for gensim summarization, newline and full stop will divide the sentence.

```
 from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize


summarize("punctual in time.")
```

this will throw Same error ValueError: input must have more than one sentence

now when there is something after full stop it will interpret it as more than one sentence

```
summarize("punctual in time. good subject knowledge")     
#o/p will be blank string since the text is very small, and now you won't receive any error
''
```

Now coming to ur problem, you need to join all the element into one string

```
 #example
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[["good subject."," punctual in time.","discipline person."]]], columns = ['comment'])

print(df)
    comment
0   [good subject., punctual in time, discipline ...

df['comment'] = df['comment'].apply(''.join)


df['comment'].apply(summarize) #this will work for you but keep in mind you have long text to generate summary
```

Comment: Thank you so much @qaiser but when I try to summarize a specific column like:
`df["comments"][2].apply(summarize)`
I get an error
`'str' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: Because df['comments'][2] is a string, remove [2] in ur above code

Answer (score 0):

got the solution, Actually Pandas has inbuilt methods for that to be done. Just follow the below piece of code if some of you face the same problem.

`df["comments"] = df["comments"].str.replace(",","").astype(str)
df["comments"] = df["comments"].str.replace("[","").astype(str)
df["comments"] = df["comments"].str.replace("]","").astype(str)
df["comments"] = df["comments"].str.replace("'","").astype(str)`

Doing this will remove all the square brackets and commas from the list and the feedback will be treated as one single string. Then you can summarize the text present in the rows of a dataframe using:

`from gensim.summarization import summarize
summary = summarize(df["comment[i]"])
print(summary)`